# python regex for a letter must be surrounded by a another letter

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regex that only matches a string that includes lowercase a & b  such that each a has the letter b immediately before it and after it.

e.g., the Regex should match the string 'bbbabbababbbbab' but not 'abbbbaabbab'

I have written an expression that does satisfy the example however, the regex should also match a string such as 'bab' but it does not.

My current expression is `^[b]+(ab)+[ab]*[b]$`

Anyone have any advice on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Is `a` presence required? You might want `^b+(?:ab+)+$` or `^(?:b+a(?!$)b*)+$` then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeating single chars ab in the group `(ab)+`

You can repeat the a's and the b's as well:

```
^b+(?:a+b+)*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6mH6F1/1)

If you only want to match a single `a` and the a should be there at least once:

```
^b+(?:ab+)+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cncC71/1)

Comment: If I understand well, each `a` must be surrounded by `b`s. It's no more the case if you write `a+` in the first pattern.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yes in the case of multiple a's and b's the statement was not correct about the `[ab]*` part as there is a `b$`